# How to add event on the context menu for chart in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, event-handling, contextmenu

I have a chart in WPF and when I right click on the chart it goes to the function Chart_mouseRightButtonDown which is described below.I want to add a context menu.I have already added two options to the context menu.but now I want some action when a user click ont hose options.How to add a handler to it ?

```
private void Chart_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var originalSource = e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject;
        if (originalSource is Ellipse)
        {
            ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();

            contextMenu.Items.Add("Lookup Details in Grid");
            contextMenu.Items.Add("Lookup Defect Info");

            runTrendChart.ContextMenu = contextMenu;

        }
        else
            runTrendChart.ContextMenu = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding just strings to `ContextMenu` `Items` collection you should add a new MenuItem element:

```
contextMenu.Items.Add(MenuItem() 
{
Header = "Lookup Details in Grid",
Command = ANY_COMMAND_YOU_WANT
});
```

I don't see the reason why you are adding this MenuItems in `MouseRightButtonDown` handler instead of XAML, but this should solve your problem.

*Edit* If you don't want to use a `Command` the `MenuItem` has a `Click` event to which you can add an event handler.